# From where can I refer a friend to visit stackoverflow.com?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, growth

It would be nice if we can spread the world, by just one click - email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much everyone knows about it already... and if they don't: **SHAME ON THEM**

Answer (score 7):

This would open up stack overflow to sending people unsolicited e-mail.

If you want to refer someone to Stack Overflow, send them an e-mail yourself. If it's not worth the effort to send an e-mail, then is it worth referring them at all? How hard is it to send an e-mail?

Answer (score 4):

Write to your friend. Ask him/her about his/her life. Then, mention Stack Overflow.

I do it all the time.

Comment: okk ok I understood !!!